# Excel VBA sum with dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a excel macro calculating a sum of values in column A, using a certain dynamic range.

Basic excel example screenshot included below:

[image: Excel snapshot]

The final goal is to loop through the cells in column B till a "0" is reached. When a "0" is reached, in column A of that same row, a sum of all the values in column A is calculated until a new "0" in column B is reached. 
So in this basic example A1 should contain =sum(A2:A7) and A8 should contain the sum of the values A9 through A14.

My progress so far included below, still pretty new at all the VBA stuff.

```
Sub sumtill0()
'
' sumtill0 Macro
'

'
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
If Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 1).Value = nil And Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 1).Value <> "0" Then
    Sheets("Blad1").Activate
    Cells(2, 1).Range("A1").Select
       Else
    Dim artTekst As String
    If Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 2).Value = "0" Then
        Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 1).Fomula = "=SUM()"
    Else
        If Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Value = "0" Then
            Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "0"
            Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Fomula = "=SUM(???)"
            ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2).Value
    End If

End If

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does the code not work? Is it always the case that A is only blank when B is zero?

Comment: The code isn't ready because I don't succeed at finding the write code to define the range of the sum.
A could be blank even if B isn't zero.

Comment: Does it have to be vba? because a formula will do this

Comment: The worksheet containing these values is created, using a macro, so I hoped to include the automatic sum. The macro's purpose is also used to find all the zero values in column B, if just using a fomula, I could manually select the range at all the zero's. That's no problem ofcourse, but with an excel file with over 2k rows, would be a little bit time consuming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this does what you want. It uses the Find method to find successive zeros and sums the range between each pair. If it cycles back to the start value, it sums to the bottom value (not sure what should happen if the first value in B is not zero).

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, s As String, r1 As Range

With Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rFind = .Find(What:=0, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, searchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        s = rFind.Address
        Do
            Set r1 = rFind
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            If rFind.Address = s Then
                Set rFind = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
                r1.Offset(, -1).Value = Application.Sum(Range(r1.Offset(1, -1), rFind.Offset(, -1)))
                Exit Sub
            End If
            r1.Offset(, -1).Value = Application.Sum(Range(r1.Offset(1, -1), rFind.Offset(-1, -1)))
        Loop While rFind.Address <> s
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm, only small thing is it only calculates the sum if there's a zero at the end, so the sum corresponding to the last zero results in a 'blank sum'. This is solved by just adding a zero to the end of the file, is it also possible to include the last sum in the code?
The first value is always zero so that's no problem :)

Comment: What should the sum be though if the last value is zero?

Comment: The sum of all values until the end is reached

Comment: But the range being summed starts after the zero. Are you saying values continue in A after the last cell in B, or am I missing something?

Comment: If the last 3 rows par exemple contain
| |0|
|5|3|
|6|1|
The result gives 
|5|0|
|5|3|
|6|1|
 (instead of 11)

Comment: Had forgotten I changed code above but not in my sheet. Have made another small change above which should rectify the problem now.